# how do I refer to a control in ms access

Tags: ms-access, reference

I have created a log in  screen. My form has a command button and a text box controls. I have written a code in command button click event to check the pass word entered in the text box. while I run this program I am getting the following error.

"You can't reference a property or method for a control unless the control has the focus."

I am looking forward for your help to rectify this error.

I am very new to the ms access programming.

Comment: Please always post code for code error questions, indicating the line on which the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like:

```
txtPassword.SetFocus
```

and then you can detect it like:

```
If Screen.ActiveControl = txtPassword Then
   If txtPassword.Text = xyz Then
     'Do something
   End If

End If
```

Comment: I would not. The .text property of controls in MS Access is only available when the control has focus and are quite probably the cause of the error. I would use nothing, because the default property is .value, but if you insist on a property, .value is the one you want.